# determine mysql version from mysql itself

Tags: mysql, version

I already know this command in Linux

```
mysql --version #outputs version of MySQL
```

But I have a case where I can't get access to the server, but can connect to the db.

Is there a MYSQL query which will output its own version?

Comment: something like `show variables like '%version%'  `

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-variables.html)

```
show variables like '%version%';
```

Comment: the answer being correct, you should mark it so other people looking this up in the future know...

Comment: Or `SELECT @@VERSION;`.

Answer (score 0):

Example: Unix command(*root* is the MYSQL username),

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";'
```

Sample outputs:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.49                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

In above case mysql version is **5.5.49**.

Please find [this useful reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tell-version-mysql-unix-linux-command/).